# $E$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if $\delta E$ ($\delta >0$) is Lebesgue measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

To start with, I have proved that the proposition is true if $E$ is a cube. But I am not sure about the next step.

Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is Lebesgue measurable. Then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists open set $O$ such that $E\subset O$ and $m_*(O-E) <\epsilon$ where $m_*$ is the exterior measure. Let $O-E = \cup_{j=1}^\infty Q_j$ be a cube covering. (Not sure if I have to use $\infty$? Will some finite number $k$ do it?). Then

$$m_*(\delta(O-E)) = m_*(\delta O - \delta E) \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty m_* (\delta Q_j) = \delta^n \sum_{j=1}^\infty m_*(Q_j) <\delta^n \epsilon$$

Since we can let $\delta^n \epsilon$ be arbitrarily small (Is this correct?) and $\delta O$ is open, $\delta E$ is measurable.

Suppose $\delta E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable. Do we just use the same argument (if the above argument is correct) but instead of multiplying by $\delta$, we multiply by $\frac{1}{\delta}$?

Comment: Is $\delta$ a number? operator? other?

Comment: @AdamHughes It is a number greater than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks good. If you want another perspective, here's my favorite way.

Multiplication by $\delta$ is a homeomorphism, hence it takes open sets to open sets. But then if $E$ is in your $\sigma$-algebra, $\Sigma$, then it is generated by open sets and the $\sigma$-algebra operations, which commute with inverse images.

So write $\delta E$ as the same limit of those open sets all dilated by $\delta$, since the operations commute, you see that $E\in\Sigma$ implies $\delta E\in \Sigma$, and similarly for the converse using dilation by $\delta^{-1}$.

Comment: That's an interesting perspective. I just started so I might want to read $\sigma$-algebra first... Regarding the choice of cube covering, does it really matter if I use $k$ instead of $\infty$?

Comment: @Misakov yes it does:  finitely many cubes mean your set is **bounded** but remember not all measurable sets are bounded.